# Contador com Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Existe alguma forma de criar um tipo de contador com Ajax?

Tenho o código abaixo, que ao efetuarmos um submit em um form, ele chama este ajax, e executa os processos pré definidos.

Gostaria de saber se após 3 eventos (clicks) o ajax direcionar o usuário para outra página.

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#addpayment').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "redir.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function envio()
                {    
                     var cont = "Pagamento realizado.";
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.color="#FF0000";
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").innerHTML = cont ;
                     setTimeout(function() {
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.display="none";},3000);
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.display="inline"



                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="addpayment" name="addpayment" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>


    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group" align="center" >
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Enviar" >
       </form>
       <div id=sucesso></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Você quer que, quando o usuário clicar 3 vezes no botão "Enviar", ele seja redirecionado para outra página?

Comment: Uai, faz uma variavel normal e vai incrementando-a a cada clique. Quando tiver 3 redireciona o cara com o window.href.

Comment: @valdeir, sim exatamente.

Comment: @Francisco, minha dificuldade é esta. Gerar um contador (variável e ir incrementando). Não conheço muito a sintaxe do Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta criar uma variável global e ir somando ou comparando o valor.

Na verdade isso não é feito com Ajax e sim com Javascript. O **[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** é apenas uma função do jQuery que serve para fazer as requisições.

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      // Numero de click
      var totalClicks = 0;

        jQuery('#addpayment').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        // Verifica se o valor da variável totalClicks representa 3 clicks.
        // Caso o número seja menor que 3 clicks, ignora esse trecho
        if (totalClicks >= 2) {
            alert("Você será redirecionado");

            // Aqui você coloca toda a função que você quer que o algoritmo faça ao completar os 3 cliks

            window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/nova_pagina.html" //Essa linha vai redirecionar o usuário para "https://www.example.com/nova_pagina.html"

            return false;
        }

        // Aqui você coloca toda a função que você quer que o algoritmo faça antes de completar os 3 cliks

        //Soma o valor de totalClicks + 1
        totalClicks++;

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "redir.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function envio()
                {    
                     var cont = "Pagamento realizado.";
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.color="#FF0000";
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").innerHTML = cont ;
                     setTimeout(function() {
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.display="none";},3000);
                     document.getElementById("sucesso").style.display="inline"



                }

            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="addpayment" name="addpayment" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>


    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group" align="center" >
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Enviar" >
       </form>
       <div id=sucesso></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
```

Resumo:

A variável `totalClicks` não recebe o evento de click. Ela apenas irá receber o número de cliques.

O elemento que irá receber os eventos, é o botão de enviar. Ele ficará responsável por verificar o número de cliques, redirecionar a página e enviar os dados via POST.

Funcionamento:

1. Em `var totalClicks = 0;` definimos que, ao completar o carregamento da página, o valor de clique será igual a 0
2. O botão `Enviar` recebe o evento de `submit`
3. Quando o botão recebe esse evento, nós fazemos uma comparação com `if (totalClicks >= 2) {`. Nesse caso utilizei o número dois porque somente depois faço a soma total de cliques.
4. Nessa linha `totalClicks++;` somamos o número de cliques. Isso equivale à `totalClicks = totalClicks + 1;`

Comment: grato pela ajuda. !

Comment: funcionou como esperado. Gostaria de entender apenas como que esta variável (totalclicks) recebe o evento do click. Grato

Comment: @user54154 adicionei um resumo e o funcionamento.

Comment: @grato Valdeir.